Why is draggable id not found even though I can see it trough inspector?
While using react-beautiful-dnd in my react app I stumble upon an issue.
After reorder a DND list, I end up not being able to move the replaced item since it may not have a draggable id.Unable to find draggable with id: 1037
Thing is the component has a draggable id as it shows in inspector.
inspector
{
  "draggableId": "1037",
  "index": 3,
  "isDragDisabled": false,
  "children": "ƒ () {}",
  "isClone": false,
  "isEnabled": true,
  "canDragInteractiveElements": false,
  "shouldRespectForcePress": false,
  "mapped": {
    "type": "SECONDARY",
    "offset": "{x: 0, y: 0}",
    "combineTargetFor": null,
    "shouldAnimateDisplacement": true,
    "snapshot": "{combineTargetFor: null, combineWith: null, draggin…}"
  }

My reorder function is the following
const reorder = (list, startIndex, endIndex) => {
        const result = [...list]
        const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1)
        result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed)
        return result
    }

Tried to remove Strictmode since it may cause issue when rerender but this did not solve issue.
Any idea would be appreaciated, thanks for reading
EDIT: Ended up solving the issue by using the index as draggableId casted to string insted of object id source
<Draggable
 draggableId={String(index)}
 index={index}
 key={index}>

